# Is there a real-world basis for this interrogation technique?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

In the latter part of [eps2.9_pyth0n-pt1.p7z](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5831628), the focus is on

> Angela's abduction and interrogation by WhiteRose,

following a(n all-night?) long ride in the back of a van, one with an extremely odd playlist.  Once she arrives, she is first interviewed by

> a girl who appears to be a younger version of herself,

who asks a series of surreal questions, as prompted by a

> Commodore 64 choose-your-own-adventure style DOS game

while, in the background of an otherwise dark room, a fishtank slowly leaks.  What.

I've watched this episode a handful of times, and I have yet to understand why she is questioned in such a strange way.  Whatever "belief" was being elicited, couldn't it have been discussed, like, in a warehouse?

WR wasn't interested in scaring her, nor was he interested in her data, he said so explicitly.  My questions are: **Is there a real-world basis for the bizarre interrogation technique?  Is there something in either Eastern mysticism or psychological warfare that would explain this scene?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there is a real world basis for the interrogation technique. This interview of a Mr. Robot writer has some insight into the meaning and reasoning behind this [interrogation technique](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/tv/mr-robot/258492/mr-robot-writer-explains-the-weird-room-scenes-with-angela).

> The questionnaire in the game is designed to gauge how malleable Angela is. I actually love how the game's questions and the content of the phone call are reminiscent of those old C64 adventure games. The little girl showing Angela her bruises could be perceived as a test of Angela's empathy. While the rest of the house has a contemporary décor, that room feels like it’s from a different time. This scene always makes me think of 2001: A Space Odyssey, where Dave Bowman finds himself in that neoclassical style bedroom where time is completely warped.

And the reasoning behind the fish tank leaking.

> The room is full of references to time or of how time is fleeting. This includes the old rotary phone, the Commodore 64, the leaking fish tank, and the ‘hang in there’ poster. There is also this notion of games here. The little girl loads a game from a disk, which has some other fun games stored on it. The reference to Lolita is not only connected to the location of the key, but many of the characters in Lolita consistently engage in games and puzzles.